sudo not prompting for password despite apparently good sudoers configuration
This initially recently, seemingly spontaneously began on a particular Ubuntu 22.04 install (located on a VPS, if that matters). T'was later upgraded to 24.04, the issue continued.
What happens is when commands with sudo are typed, ie:
sudo apt update
Command runs successfully but without ever prompting user for password no matter how much time has elapsed or if the machine was freshly started after shut down or reboot. My expectation and experience with every other Ubuntu install has been that sudo should prompt user for password, unless within whatever the default timeout window is.
This is being accessed via ssh and the same effect is observed regardless of which device I'm ssh-ing in from. Reaching here after some time spent Googling, Redditing, GPT-ing, etc.
Here are the contents of /etc/sudoers:
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        timestamp_timeout=0
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# This fixes CVE-2005-4890 and possibly breaks some versions of kdesu
# (#1011624, https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452532)

# This preserves proxy settings from user environments of root
# equivalent users (group sudo)
#Defaults:%sudo env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy all_proxy no_proxy"

# This allows running arbitrary commands, but so does ALL, and it means
# different sudoers have their choice of editor respected.
#Defaults:%sudo env_keep += "EDITOR"

# Completely harmless preservation of a user preference.
#Defaults:%sudo env_keep += "GREP_COLOR"

# While you shouldn't normally run git as root, you need to with etckeeper
#Defaults:%sudo env_keep += "GIT_AUTHOR_* GIT_COMMITTER_*"

# Per-user preferences; root won't have sensible values for them.
#Defaults:%sudo env_keep += "EMAIL DEBEMAIL DEBFULLNAME"

# "sudo scp" or "sudo rsync" should be able to use your SSH agent.
#Defaults:%sudo env_keep += "SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_AUTH_SOCK"

# Ditto for GPG agent
#Defaults:%sudo env_keep += "GPG_AGENT_INFO"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "@include" directives:

@includedir /etc/sudoers.d

There was nothing in /etc/sudoers.d aside from a README, deleting that had no effect. Executing sudo -k produces no output and subsequent commands issued with sudo still do not prompt for password.
Output of sudo -l looks like this:
Matching Defaults entries for myUser on myMachine:
    env_reset, timestamp_timeout=0, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User myUser may run the following commands on myMachine:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL

Typing simply su does prompt me for root password, which does work.
I have tried creating a fresh new user, adding that user to sudo group, and the same effect is observed for that new user, they never are prompted for password when using sudo commands. I compared sudoers and also PAM and Polkit policy configuration on this machine vs other working ones and nothing stood out for me.
In another similar issue posted here, they found some things missing in pam-auth-update. In my case it only shows:
 │  [*] Unix authentication                                                                                                       │  
 │  [*] Register user sessions in the systemd control group hierarchy                                                             │  
 │  [*] Create home directory on login                                                                                            │  
 │  [*] Inheritable Capabilities Management   

Output of /etc/pam.d/sudo:
#%PAM-1.0

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required   pam_limits.so

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive

The uncommented output of /etc/pam.d/common-auth:
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
auth    optional            pam_cap.so 

Output of sudo sudo -V | grep Configure:
Configure options: --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-option-checking --disable-silent-rules --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --with-all-insults --with-pam --with-pam-login --with-fqdn --with-logging=syslog --with-logfac=authpriv --with-devel --with-env-editor --with-editor=/usr/bin/editor --with-timeout=15 --with-password-timeout=0 --with-passprompt=[sudo] password for %p:  --with-tty-tickets --without-lecture --disable-root-mailer --with-sendmail=/usr/sbin/sendmail --with-rundir=/run/sudo --with-sssd --with-sssd-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-zlib=system --enable-admin-flag --with-apparmor --with-selinux --with-linux-audit --enable-tmpfiles.d=/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d MVPROG=/bin/mv --with-exampledir=/usr/share/doc/sudo/examples

I'm sure I must be missing something obvious. Any help on how to narrow this down would be much appreciated!

Try removing "Defaults        timestamp_timeout=0"

@ubfan1 I did remove that, unfortunately to no effect

@steeldriver done, updated comment with update from those

Does your user actually have a password?  Did you actually put in a root password (for su to succeed)?  The password sudo asks for is the user password, not sure what happens if the user doesn't have one.

@noob1827200 thanks - that's ruled out a few things

@ubfan1 my user does have a password. i did put a root password for su to succeed. I understand the password sudo asks for is the user password. The user does have a password, it's just never being asked for it when issuing sudo commands. It used to. Not sure what could have possibly changed.

Assuming that the behaviour you are experiencing is due to passwordless accounts.
The pam stack is accepting these "logins" due to nullok .
In /etc/pam.d/common-auth removing nullok on the pam_unix.so will require password for login operations like console and sudo:
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
auth    optional            pam_cap.so

